# Bizarre Hapi error - Requests failing between onRequest and onPreAuth

Tags: hapi.js

All of a sudden I have a very bizarre error. I cannot access any of the endpoints on my API. The request hits the API, the 'onRequest' hook is fired, and then it does not hit a breakpoint in the next hook, 'onPreAuth', meaning that the requests are failing some point between there.

I have absolute no errors, and **this is also happening in production**. I did not push any changes to my code; this just started happening.

Is it possible to see why the requests are failing between onRequest and onPreAuth? I'm at a complete loss here, and it's affecting my production code.

```
server.ext('onRequest', (request, reply) => {
  console.log('onRequest'); // Gets hit
});

server.ext('onPreAuth', (request, reply) => {
  console.log('onPreAuth'); // Nothing here or below is hit
});

server.ext('onPostAuth', (request, reply) => {
  console.log('onPostAuth');
});

server.ext('onPreHandler', (request, reply) => {
  console.log('onPostAuth');
});

server.on('request-error', function (request, err) { 
  console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: How and what do you log?  Are you seeing anything in logs?

Comment: @simon-p-r I have logging in handlers, and I'm currently using the lifecycle hooks to check where the request gets to. I've updated my OP. I guess what I need to do is find out where this errors is being logged to?